# Use of homological Cauchy theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the oriented circumferences $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$,$\gamma_3$ such that $\gamma_1$ is positively oriented, $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ are negatively oriented and contained in the interior of $\gamma_1$, besides that $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ are disjoint and their interior also.

Let $\Gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3$ and the set $A=\{z\in\mathbb C : Ind_\Gamma(z)=1\}$. Suppose that $0\in V$.

1. If $\Omega$ is an open connected set containing $\overline A$ and $g$ an holomorphic function on $\Omega$, determine $f$ holomorphic function on $\Omega$ knowing that for all $z\in A$, $$f(z)=\int_\Gamma \frac{g(t)(1-\cos(t))}{t^2(t-z)}dt$$
2. Let $a\in A$ such that $a\neq0$ e $g(a)(1-\cos(a))\neq0$. Compute $$\lambda=\int_\Gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)}dz$$

I'm trying to resolve this problem.

For the item 1, I considered the function $$h(t)=\frac{g(t)(1-\cos(t))}{t^2}$$ and by the homological Cauchy theorem $$f(z)=\int_\Gamma\frac{g(t)(1-\cos(t))}{t^2(t-z)}dt=\int_\Gamma\frac{h(t)}{t-z}dt=2\pi i h(t)Ind_\Gamma(z)=2\pi i h(t)=2\pi i \frac{g(z)(1-\cos(z))}{z^2}$$.
But, I also know that $\int_\Gamma=\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}+\int_{\gamma_3}$ and I don't know how to use it since $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ are oriented differently.

For the item 2, I think I will use the Cauchy's integral formula derivatives.Thus $\lambda=2\pi i f'(z)$.

Is what my approach is correct?